# X^2+X+1 over GF(2) is a unsolvable polynomial having a solvable group?

Tags: galois-theory

If F is a field of characteristic 0, then it is well known that a polynomial over F is solvable by radicals if and only if its Galois group is a solvable group.

Is there possible to find a simple polynomial f over GF(2) having a solvable galois group but f is not solvable by radicals ?

In the book of Lisl Gaal "Galois Theory with examples", it is claimed that the polynomial X^2+X+1 over F=GF(2) get a solvable Galois group (I am OK with this claim) and that X^2+X+1 is not solvable by radicals. I don't understand why it is not solvable by radicals. Lisl Gaal claimed that, if it were solvable by radical, we would be able to find  a field F(\sqrt(m)) with m in F such that any root of f is in F(\sqrt(m)) but I don't understand why. I recall that a polynomial over F is called solvable by radicals if its splitting field is included in a radical extension of F.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you mean with "radical extension".

Wikipedia says that splitting fields of Artin Schreier polynomials in positive charcteristic are radical extensions, which I find a bit surprising. If you allow them, I think we get the equivalence solvable group <=> subfield of a  radical extension. Anyway, here $X^2+X+1$ is an Artin-Schreier polynomial.

If you don't allow for Artin Schreier polynomials, the rest of definition says,
"a simple extension F/K generated by a single element $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha^n=b$ for an element $b$ of $K$".
Note that it doesn't require $n$ to be the degree of the extension nor $X^n-b$ to be irreducible. In this case your extension is still radical because if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^2+X+1$ then $\alpha^3 = 1 \in \Bbb F_2$.

Finally if you put a restriction and only allow $n$th roots where $X^n-a$ is irreducible (I don't think this is the standard meaning), then $\Bbb F_2$ has no radical extension *at all* because $X^n$ and $X^n-1$ are always reducible.

Comment: I mean E is a radical extension of F in the sens that there exists a finite number of fields such that F<F_1<...<F_k=E where F_{i+1} is generated over F_i by a single element \alpha_i satisfying \alpha_i^{n_i}=b_i with b_i in F_i. If I undersand well your answer, X^2+X+1 is solvable by radicals over GF(2) and, following your reasonning, any polynomial of degree 2 over a finite field is also solvable by radicals. So, do you know a polynomial f  over a finite field having a solvable galois group but f is not solvable by radical ?

Comment: all the finite fields are radical extensions of the base field because they are all of the form $\Bbb F_p(a)$ with $a^n=1$ for some $n$

Comment: the standard example of an extension that has a solvable galois group and is not a subfield of a radical extension (so not solvable by radical) is $X^p -X - t$ over $\Bbb F_p(t)$

Comment: I agree. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$.

Since $f$ is quadratic and has no roots in $F_2$, it follows that $f$ is irreducible over $F_2$.

Any field containing one of the roots of $f$ contains the other one, since for example, by Vieta's formulas, the sum of the roots is $-1$ (which also equals $1$).

Thus, if $K$ is any splitting field of $f$ over $F_2$, then $[K:F_2]=2$.

It's clear that $K$ can't satisfy $K=F_2(\sqrt{m})$, for some nonzero $m \in F_2$, since the only nonzero element of $F_2$ is $1$, whose *only* square root is itself.

However, if $w$ is a root of $f(x)$, then
\begin{align*}
&f(w) = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&w^2 + w + 1 = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(w-1)(w^2 + w + 1) = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&w^3 - 1 = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&w^3 = 1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
So $K$ *is* a simple radical extension of $F_2$ by a cube root of $1$.

Thus, Gaal is correct when he claims $K$ is not of the form $F_2\left(\sqrt{m}\right)$, but not correct when he claims that $K$ is not a radical extension of $F_2$.

Comment: As simple as that. +1

Comment: Please, can you give some details for your claim : If K was a radical extension of F_2, then necessarily K=F_2(\sqrt{m}), for some m in F_2. Moreover, my question was : is K *included* in a radical extension.

Comment: @L. ZWALD: I've edited my answer, reversing my previous claim.  Although $K$ is not an radical extension of $F_2$ by a square root, it _is_ a radical extension of $F_2$ by a cube root.